# How to configure Angular universal(Angular 6) + Socket.io + Node API server project(MEAN stack with Angular universal and Socket.io)?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, angular6, angular-universal

I am newb to Angular universal and Socket.io.

I want to create a MEAN stack project with `Angular-universal`(Angular-6) for server side rendering, `Socket.io` and `Node` API server(express) project.

I have used `angular-cli` 6 for generating Angular-6 project.

So, my question is How to configure Angular-universal(Angular 6) + Socket.io + Node API server project(MEAN stack with Angular universal and Socket.io).

Any articles or blog would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has been quite a time since you made this question. Did you get any solution? I am facing the same problem: Don't know how to configure Socket.io on Angular Universal. If you got a solution, please share it.